# Python libais documentation

Tags: python, ais

I cannot find any documentation about what does the ais.decode means.
I do not know from where these categories (e.g. u'slot_timeout') had been chosen.

I tried to find it on Internet, but I found many different solution from different web sites (no one were talking about libais...).

Can you explain me what I should read when it is wrote

```
u'slot_timeout': 1L,
u'sync_state': 0L,
[...]
u'special_manoeuvre': 0L
```

Thanks

Comment: http://catb.org/gpsd/AIVDM.html suggests that special_manoeuvre = 0 means "Not available" (table 8), slot_timeout = 1 means "10 minutes" (table 41). I found this link at https://github.com/schwehr/libais/tree/master/docs

Comment: That’s it :) , I don’t know why but I had not seen the docs folder :/